# LINQ to SQL, How to make a one to many relationship for one table?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, windows-phone-8

I need to implement this relationship:

- each folder can contain many folders inside it.
- each folder can be inside one parent folder.
- and there can be shortcuts of the folder inside many other folders

So, I think it is all about just one table, `folder`. How can I apply these relationships? thanks.

```
[Table]
public class Folder
{
    private int id;
    [Column(DbType = "INT NOT NULL IDENTITY", IsDbGenerated = true, IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set
        {
            id = value;
        }
    }

    private string name;
    [Column]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != name)
            {
                name = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more about table design than L2S. Once you have this design in your database, the Linq-2-sql part is straightforward.

> each folder can contain many folders inside it.  each folder can be
>   inside one parent folder.

This could be a Folder table with an optional foreign key to itsself called parent_folder_id or something like that.

> and there can be shortcuts of the folder inside many other folders

This probably requires an extra table or a bit of tweaking inside the folder table like add a boolean IsShortcut and a second optional foreign key to the folder it is a shortcut to.